# Template member function cannot be explicitly specialized

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, c++-templates

I have a declaration of a function in class

```
class A { 
  template<typename T, typename... ARGS>
  void Func( ARGS&&... args) {
     //DoSomeWork
  }
};
```

and then try to specialize it for some type like this

```
template<>
void A::Func<int>(bool arg) {
//DoSomeOtherWork
}
```

I get error

> error C2910: 'A::Func': cannot be explicitly specialized

Is there a way to specialize the template or do I have to find a workaround? If there is no way to specialize the template, why is that the case?

Comment: MSVC is just being unhelpful. Clang says `error: no function template matches function template specialization 'Func'` `note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'ARGS &&' against 'bool'`, and replacing `bool` with `bool &&` makes it work, including on MSVC.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Now that you mentioned it, I remembered I was dealing with this a long time ago. When the variadic template is of the form ARGS&&..., the arguments must either be '&&' or 'const &'. Can you please add your comment as an answer?

Comment: Same problem & solution [Problems when specializing variadic template member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77377700/problems-when-specializing-variadic-template-member-function/77378020#77378020)

Comment: This question is being discussed [on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427028/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specialization can't change argument types. If `Func` (the primary template) accepts parameters by reference, the specialization must do so too, e.g.:

```
template<>
void A::Func<int>(bool &&arg) {}
```

Also MSVC is being suprisingly unhelpful in this case. Clang does a better job:

```
<source>:9:9: error: no function template matches function template specialization 'Func'
    9 | void A::Func<int>(bool arg) {
      |         ^
<source>:3:8: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'ARGS &&' against 'bool'
    3 |   void Func( ARGS&&... args) {
      |        ^
```